# Array of selected options in Form::select?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an array that contains ids of selected options in select list (html).
In Laravel it looks as:

```
<?=Form::select('type_work[]', $work_types, old('type_work'), ['multiple' => "multiple", 'size' => 15, 'id' => 'type_work', "class" => "selectpicker form-control"]);?>
```

Where second parameter is incoming data to build options, and third parameter is array of selected options (id).

Why it does not work in Laravel?

This is incoming data:

```
Collection {#488 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    14 => "Роботи, пов’язані з проведенням технічної експертизи."
  ]
}
```

This is selected data:

```
Collection {#408 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    14 => "Роботи, пов’язані з проведенням технічної експертизи."
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, I use `multiple` list

Comment: which version of laravel are you using; php artisan --version will tell you

Comment: I use 5.3 VERSION

Comment: okay, the second parameters needs to be an associative array

Comment: like $users = Users::lists('username', 'id');
Form::select('user', $users);

Comment: and also as 4th param you should specify that it is multiple select like this:

`['multiple' => 'multiple']`

Comment: So, should be array with id and name that used in select as main array?

Comment: it does not work still, look updated qustion please

Comment: you will have to setup laravel collective from this docs https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The amount type_work[] you have used is considered as the ID of the field. You must specify the value of the Name as an array.

Change the code as below

```
{{Form::select('type_work',$work_types,null,array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'type_work[]'))}}
```

Answer (score -1):

So you code should be like

```
<?=Form::select('type_work[]', $work_types, null, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 15, 'id' => 'type_work', "class" => "selectpicker form-control"]);?>
```

[Reference](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tip-formselect)

[Docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

Comment: Key and value should be same?

Comment: No, but looking at what you used above, they don't have to be

Comment: like the user I used for the form above, the id will be hidden while the username will be shown.

Comment: Why you deleted `[]` from name and why third parameter is null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182967/discussion-between-wadleo-and-opv).